# How to consume several records from kafka in flink app?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I would appreciate if you advise how to do:
I need to read records from Kafka topic for 10 seconds and then store result in an object for further processing (i.e., need to read multiple records at once).

As I understood, there are two possible approaches:

1. Implementing `SourceFunction` and attempting to read batches within it. However, I didn't figure out how to get specific record to accumulate.
2. Use timers in `processElement` function. This way, the function would be called for each new record, and then emit the result based on the timer tick.

Is it necessary to use timestamps and watermarks or not?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I think you should use Windowing. Take a look **[here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/concepts/time/#windowing)**

Comment: I agree with @Niko. Also, watermarks are especially needed when you are dealing with event timestamps.